# How to get backgroundColor of element when it is set by the CSS property background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

One way to set the background-color property of an element is by using `background: #someColorValue`. However, doing this will not change the `backgroundColor` property in the `style` of that element. As a result, when I use `element.style.backgroundColor`, it returns an empty string.
This problem doesn't occur when setting color directly using the `background-color` property. Why does this happen??

Comment: Try the computed style. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: you want to get the value of the background css property using javascript?

Comment: @Lain Thanks it works, but what happen here?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Lain I mean what happens when we use the computed style method? and why this problem did not happen when use background-color.

Comment: The `Window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain. Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object, or by indexing with CSS property names. You get the style the browser displays in the end after applying all stylings.

Comment: Could you try inserting a snippet demonstrating your problem? Currently, I cannot understand what problem you're facing specifically. Adding a snippet that demonstrates the problem exactly and how you encountered that problem will help a lot. To add a snippet, you can use `Ctrl+M`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access the `style` ([`ElementCSSInlineStyle.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style)) property of an element, you are accessing its **inline style**. This means that if you give an element a style via a class, you still cannot access it through `style`. As a result, it will return you an empty string (`''`).

[`Window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), on the other hand, returns:

> ... the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain

This means that you can access the style that is given via a class, simply because it gives you all CSS properties **after** applying all active stylesheets (including those applied via a class).

In your particular case, you're trying to access `background`. `background` CSS property is actually a [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) that also sets a lot of other background-related CSS properties. When you specify only the color using `background`, the other properties will automatically be inserted with their default values. You can access this `background` property through `ElementCSSInlineStyle.style`. However, when accessing `background` in the object `Window.getComputedStyle` returns, you will **always** get an empty string. This is because the object returned does not have the key `background`; it only has the keys for each background-related CSS properties (e.g. `background-color`, `background-clip`, etc.).

Here's a simple example demonstrating how you cannot access a non-inline style through `style` property of an element, and also how you cannot access the value of a property that is shorthand through the object `Window.getComputedStyle`

```js
const boxOne = document.querySelector('#boxOne')
const boxTwo = document.querySelector('#boxTwo')

console.log(`Box One: background ${boxOne.style['background']}, background-color ${boxOne.style['background-color']}`)

console.log(`Box Two: background ${boxTwo.style['background']}, background-color ${boxTwo.style['background-color']}`)

const boxOneComputedStyles = getComputedStyle(boxOne)
const boxTwoComputedStyles = getComputedStyle(boxTwo)

// There's no 'background' key in getComputedStyle

console.log(`Box One (Computed Styles): background ${boxOneComputedStyles['background']}, background-color ${boxOneComputedStyles['background-color']}`)

console.log(`Box Two (Computed Styles): background ${boxTwoComputedStyles['background']}, background-color ${boxTwoComputedStyles['background-color']}`)
```

```css
#boxOne,
#boxTwo {
  background: #121212DD;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxOne" style="background-color: #121212DD;"></div>
<div id="boxTwo" style="background: #121212DD;"></div>
```